# Using the getword function c++

Tags: c++, string

Am I using the getword function wrong here? The compiler keeps telling me that there is no member function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;  
int OccuranceOfString(ofstream & Out)
{
  string Occur;
  string Temp;
  int OccurLength;
  int count;

  cout << "please enter to string to search for";
  cout << endl;
  cin  >> Occur;

  OccurLength = Occur.length();

  while(Out.getword(Temp))
  {
    if (Temp == Occur)
     {
          count ++;
     }
  }    
 return  count;
}
```

Whats wrong with my code? I'm trying to find all occurances of a string with this function

Comment: You can do this pretty easy with REGEX

Comment: What's wrong with your code? `getword` is not a function in `std::ofstream`. It simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Also you may be good enough with just doing `Out >> Temp`.

Comment: so i can just replace out.getword(temp) with out >> Temp?

Comment: Why are you trying to get input from an `ofstream`?  The "o" in `ofstream` means "output".  You want `ifstream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::ofstream` has no `getword` function: see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream).

Perhaps you're thinking of [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: There is also no `std::getline` function that works with `std::ofstream`.  `std::ifstream`, yes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no function `getword` in the header files listed. You simply must construct a function that will extract words from a line. capture a line by

```
getline(out,line);
```

line will have your line of string and use line[index] to get continuous characters to be equal to a word.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

[std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

do something like this..

```
int pos = 0;
int occurrences = 0
string input = "YAaaaAH";
string find = "a";

while(pos != -1){
    pos = input.find(find,pos);
    occurrences++;
}
```

Comment: The comparison should be to `std::string::npos`, not `-1`. There is no guarantee that the two are equal.

Comment: @Yuushi `This constant is defined with a value of -1, which because size_t is an unsigned integral type, it is the largest possible representable value for this type.`  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/ correct?

Comment: Interesting, I just looked it up, and it is actually mandated by the standard. Guess I need to read more carefully before I assert things. I still think using `npos` is clearer and more idiomatic, however (and means code won't break in the (very unlikely) case the standard changes).

Answer (score 0):

text file :

[image]

code :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
int main()
{

ifstream file("DB_name_age.txt");
int index;
string name;
int age;

if(file.is_open()) 
{
    while(file  >>index >> name >>age)  
    {
        cout << index <<" "<<name <<" "<<age << endl;
    }


   }else{
    cout<< "file open fail" <<endl;
  }
  return 0;
 }
```

visual explanation:
[image]